# ASP.NET dropdownlist doesn't postback with my masterpage

Tags: asp.net, autopostback

I've tried to create a DropDownList with auto post back in an ASP.NET project:
[image: Auto postback enabled]
It doesn't work, I tried to choose another option in the list but it doesn't post back.
I've tried to make another drop down list **in another page** without my masterpage and it did post back.

Comment: Show us your code. How is anyone supposed to help you with no information?

Comment: Well, if you know about this problem you may know how to fix it, regardless of seeing the code
masterpage.aspx:
http://pastebin.com/2FHCa6Lf
code behind:
http://pastebin.com/QpKa7ipN